# JavaScript - Cache bookmarklet but always load the latest version

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, bookmarklet

I'm working on a JavaScript [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that lets users send a link to a website.
Is it possible to cache the bookmarklet but also reload it if a new version is available? 
(Maybe with htaccess?)

Edit:
This is my bookmarklet:

```
javascript:javascript:(function(){new_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');new_script.src='https://www.example.com/folder/bookmarklet.js?v=1';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_script);new_script.type='text/javascript';})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of bookmarklets is that "cache" is irrelevant to them: The exist entirely within the browser's bookmark storage, there is no server call (unless you write one as part of the bookmarklet code).

You could have your bookmarklet load and check a version string from your website using ajax or JSONP.